# how to change page title or menu title in url in php?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - How to add a pages title to the URL? And how to create a clean url using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523587/php-how-to-add-a-pages-title-to-the-url-and-how-to-create-a-clean-url-using-p)

I am using the url in my site like `http://www.example.com/details.php?cid=3`. I want to have this type of url into `http://www.example.com/PAGE-TITLE-URL or /details/page-title`.

What are the changes I have to do to get this friendly url in my site.

Comment: try example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001380/use-titles-of-pages-posts-on-the-url?rq=1

Comment: this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Answer (score 2):

For this the better suggestion will be to used .htaccess rewrite url

For more information to learn about htaccess you can see this link:-

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

and

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect